# Safari rendering issue on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css

I was wondering if anyone could take a look at this site http://dev.beckin.com/razorsharpgame/ on their iPhone and tell me why it looks like it does and how to fix it. Unfortunately I do not have an iPhone but my client does and wants it fixed. He states that (right half of footer and part of the header is covered in transparent white.)

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is what it looks like on my iPhone 4S: http://tinypic.com/r/j5zdrn/6.

Comment: Download the SDK and load it in the simulator?

Comment: Or just make a mobile-friendly version of your theme using @media queries, that's still the best option in my humble opinion.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm trying the sdk simulator now. Not sure why I would get down votes on a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iphone debug console says it has an issue with the view port meta tag.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">`

Not sure if that has something to do with it?

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how to fix that? Is that viewport in my header or is it missing?

Comment: No problem, It's currently in your header, I would try removing it and seeing if it helps.

Comment: It works fine here http://underurhat.com/ with this viewport: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> (it doesnt have the maximum-scale property).

Comment: Yup removing it seems to have fixed it, looks fine now. Try Dyn recommendation of removing the maximum scale property.

Comment: Although you have a problem with the footer, `min-width: 1100px !important;` why this min width property?

Comment: I just updated it again with you last code. Can you check it for me again? If it doesn't look good than I will remove it.

Comment: No issue has come back again.

Comment: Awesome. I also just removed the `min-width`

Comment: I'm asking the client to confirm on his as well. Thanks @vletech !!

Comment: Problem has got worse, it seems you have a few problems with width settings on a verity of elements.

Comment: Darn.. What about now. I just removed the viewport..

Comment: Yeah it all looks good now.

Comment: Thanks so much for you time @vletech Getting the client to confirm again.

Comment: ..... apart from the footer, I think you need to change the width too 100%.

Comment: I removed the `min-width` for the outer div which is set for `width: 100%`. He said he confirmed it and that fixed the issue. Thanks so much! Do you still confirm the same on your end?

Comment: Issue with the nav is fine but `#footer-bottom-outer` still has fixed widths on it... need to change this to `width:100%;` too.

Comment: @vletech can you have a look at the post page and see why it is not centered and has a scroll bar?

Comment: Sorry I had gone to bed by the time you posted the above. For some reason you have an inline-block style on the body? `body {display: inline-block;}` If you get rid of this it should be fine.